# Setting ItemsSource of a DataGrid in User Control

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, wpf-controls, datacontext

This example is a simplified version of my requirement. If i can solve this then the rest is simple (I hope). Assume I have a class hierarchy of

**Class A:**

```
Name
List <Class B>
```

**Class B:**

```
Name
List <Class C>
```

**Class C:**

```
Name
```

Each class has a separate view, view model and model. My main view places each view in a DockPanel. The view of each class is a DataGrid that simply places the names of each list. When i click on a Name of class A it shows me names of class B below. and when i click a Name of class B it shows names of class C. So basically 3 user controls that are all DataGrid controls being shown on a dockpanel in my MainView.

I am still finding my feet in MVVM and I am not sure if this is the best way to go about doing this. The way i'd go about it is that each view model will have a property called SelectedItem being bound to the SelectedItem in the DataGrid on its view. When the property is set, another property called ChildViewModel will be set. But i am not sure how to set this up in my MainView and also in each control. How do i bind the control to it's parent datacontext and how do i bind the item source to the selected item from the parent?

Answer (score 0):

I would have one ViewModel that is the DataContext for a Window/UserControl/etc that these controls are all grouped in. Then set up the collection of ClassA plus 3 SelectedItem properties. In the SelectedItem properties, you will want to set the next one to null or a default value.

```
private ObservableCollection<ClassA> _CollectionOfA;
public ObservableCollection<ClassA> CollectionOfA 
{
   get { return _CollectionOfA; }
   set
   {
      if (value == _CollectionOfA)
         return;
      _CollectionOfA = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => CollectionOfA);
   }
}

private ClassA _SelectedClassA;
public ClassA SelectedClassA 
{
   get { return _SelectedClassA; }
   set
   {
      if (value == _SelectedClassA)
         return;
      _SelectedClassA = value;
      SelectedClassB = null; //Or default this to first item in the list, etc.
      RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedClassA);
   }
}

//Repeat SelectedClassA pattern for SelectedClassB/SelectedClassC
public ClassB SelectedClassB { get; set; }
public ClassC SelectedClassC { get; set; }
```

Then in your bindings, you'll use SelectedClassA.CollectionOfClassB property as the ItemsSource for the 2nd DataGrid, etc.

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionOfClassA}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClassA}">
    //columns defined here
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClassA.CollectionOfClassB}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClassB}">
    //columns defined here
</DataGrid>
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClassB.CollectionOfClassC}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClassC}">
    //columns defined here
</DataGrid>
```

**EDIT:**
The first option is my [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) approach. Another option would be to use something like [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) which implements a [weak event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) available through it's [messenger](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696340/Thinking-in-MVVMLight-Messenger) class. In the constructor of your second ViewModel, you register to listen for changes to the SelectedItem in the first ViewModel. And in the setter of the first ViewModel you send a message that the SelectedItem changed. Here is an example of what ClassBViewModel would look like (ClassAViewModel would only need its SelectedClassA setter to send a message, no listener in the constructor. While ClassCViewModel would listen but not need to send).

```
public class ClassBViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
   private ClassA _SelectedClassA;
   public ClassA SelectedClassA 
   {
      get { return _SelectedClassA; }
      set
      {
         if (value == _SelectedClassA)
            return;
         _SelectedClassA = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedClassA);
      }
   }

   private ClassB _SelectedClassB;
   public ClassB SelectedClassB
   {
      get { return _SelectedClassB; }
      set
      {
          if (value == _SelectedClassB)
             return;
          var oldValue = _SelectedClassB;
          _SelectedClassB = value;
          Messenger.Default.Send(new PropertyChangedMessage<ClassB>(oldValue, value, "SelectedClassB"));
          RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedClassB);
      }
   }

   public ClassBViewModel()
   {
      Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<ClassA>>(this, (message) => SelectedClassA = message.NewValue);
   }
}
```

Your ClassBView xaml for the DataGrid would still look the same:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedClassA.CollectionOfClassB}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedClassB}">
    //columns defined here
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: If i understand what you are saying, my three models and 3 views models will all be connected to the same main view. What i was trying to achieve is to have a view per view model with a main view so that my my main view would not become too large.

Comment: I added another option using MVVM Light. This takes advantage of the Messenger class to communicate between ViewModels without them needing a reference to each other. You could use normal events to accomplish this since your MainViewModel has instances of your 3 other ViewModels but I think this is a better way of doing it to keep them from being coupled to each other.